# Htaccess read white list urls from database not ip addresses

Tags: php, .htaccess

If it possible to write my white list url to database and `htaccess` read from `database`

Example :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(mp4|mp3|avi)$ [NC]
RewriteCond read domains from database 
RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally you cannot do this. But. There is a module for apache mod_auth_mysql.

and htaccess would have this:

```
AuthName My Authorzation
AuthType Basic
AuthGroupFile /dev/null  # do NOT include this directive if using Apache2!!!
AuthMySQLHost localhost
AuthMySQLDB authdata
AuthMySQLUserTable user_info
AuthMySQLGroupTable my_groups
AuthMySQLGroupField user_group
require group admin
```

Read this
[enter link description here](http://modauthmysql.sourceforge.net/CONFIGURE)

Comment: can i do like this ?

httpd.conf

RewriteEngine On
RewriteMap domainmap txt:whitelist.txt
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(mp4|mp3|avi)$ [NC]
RewriteCond ${domainmap:%{HTTP_REFERER}} !^allow$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]

and than 


whitelist.txt

my_domain allow

Comment: You asked for htaccess can read the database and now you are asking for something else ??

Comment: my hosting provider says that the database does not work

Comment: "Normally you cannot do this, _but_ ..."? Certainly that is possible, you demonstrated that. So why the first claim? Why is using the module _not_ normal? That is what a modular approach offers. That makes sense.

Comment: i use shared host